# Updating a particular field

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a requirement to update a particular field in the Account Object everytime a Particular Contact is created or deleted under it. The field should update a field call "Total child objects" which is the number field.I have written the following Trigger for it which has a logical error that I am not able to figure out.

```
trigger ContactHandaler on Contact (after insert,after delete) {
     List<Account> accUpdate = new List<Account>();
     Set<ID> aID = new Set<ID>();
   Account a = new Account();

    List<Account> aList = [SELECT ID, Name FROM Account WHERE ID IN :aID];
    List<Contact> conlist =[Select ID,Name From Contact Where ID IN :aID];
    Integer count = conlist.size();
    for(Account acc : aList){


        acc.Total_Child_Objects__c= count;
        accUpdate.add(acc);
    //   System.debug('Contact counts'+acc.Contact.size());
    }
    update accUpdate;



    if(Trigger.isInsert&&Trigger.isAfter){
        for(Contact c : Trigger.New){
            aID.add(c.AccountID);
        }
    }

    if(Trigger.isDelete&&Trigger.isAfter){
        for(Contact c : Trigger.Old){
            aID.add(c.AccountID);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sanniya it would help if you actually include the error.

Answer (score 1):

Its should be

```
List<Contact> conlist =[Select ID,Name From Contact Where AccountId IN :aID];
```